# Отправка html писем

Tags: php, html

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему html письмо не приходит в должном формате.

```
mail(
    'test@gmail.com',
    'Письмо из скрипта',
    '<html><body>Привет Василий, как дела?<br />Я умею отправлять письма с помощью php! И скоро научусь отправлять письма с помощью php с вложениями! Это будет круто!</body></html>',
    "From: ivan@example.com\r\n
    Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
    X-Mailer: PHP mail script"
)
```

На почту сообщение приходит в след. виде:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Mailer: PHP mail script

<html><head><title>Вася, привет</title></head><body bgcolor="#feeffe"><font color="blue">Привет Василий, как дела?</font><br /><font color="green">Я умею отправлять письма с помощью php! И скоро научусь отправлять письма с помощью php с вложениями! Это будет круто!</font></body></html>
```

Comment: А мануал почитать не? [mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) Пример #4 Отправка HTML-сообщения

Comment: указано же все.

Answer (score 8):

Форматирование неверное.

```
mail(
    'test@gmail.com',
    'Письмо из скрипта',
    '<html><body>Привет Василий, как дела?<br />Я умею отправлять письма с помощью php! И скоро научусь отправлять письма с помощью php с вложениями! Это будет круто!</body></html>',
    "From: ivan@example.com\r\n"
    ."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP mail script"
)
```

Вот так попробуйте. Просто, перед Content-type и X-Mailer не нужные пробелы..

Comment: Спасибо сработало)!!!